# modal show loop javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

[Here is my code in js]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dag4a.png

Hello, guys. I have such a problem. When the page is loaded, pop-up windows are supposed to open. The problem is that if I do it in a for loop, it displays the window with the last element from the array. First it iterates through the array and at the end it opens one window. How to make it wait for each window to close and then open another one, if there is another one.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/Home/GetUnreadNewsFeed', function (newsFeed) {

        for (var i = 0; i < newsFeed.length; i++) {

            showNewsFeedDetails(newsFeed[i].imageFileId, newsFeed[i].title, newsFeed[i].hiperlink, newsFeed[i].idNewsFeed);
        };
    });
});

function showNewsFeedDetails(imageFileId, title, hiperlink, idNewsFeed) {
    loader.load();
    $.get('/Home/GetNewsFeedDetailsPartialView', {
        'imageFileId': imageFileId,
        'hiperlink': hiperlink
    }, function (data) {
        modal.show({
            bodyContentText: data,
            headerText: '<h5 class="heading-modal-h">' + title + '</h5>',
            btnSubmitOnClick: function () { markAsRead(idNewsFeed); },
            btnSubmit: Translations.iTookNote,
            width: '40%'
        });
    }).always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        loader.hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/Home/GetUnreadNewsFeed', async function (newsFeed) {

        for (var i = 0; i < newsFeed.length; i++) {

            await showNewsFeedDetails(newsFeed[i].imageFileId, newsFeed[i].title, newsFeed[i].hiperlink, newsFeed[i].idNewsFeed);
        };
    });
});

function showNewsFeedDetails(imageFileId, title, hiperlink, idNewsFeed) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    loader.load()
    $.get('/Home/GetNewsFeedDetailsPartialView', {
             'imageFileId': imageFileId,
             'hiperlink': hiperlink
          }, function (data) {
                modal.show({
                  bodyContentText: data,
                  headerText: '<h5 class="heading-modal-h">' + title + '</h5>',
                  btnSubmitOnClick: function () { 
                     markAsRead(idNewsFeed); 
                     resolve();
                  },
                  btnSubmit: Translations.iTookNote,
                  width: '40%'
                });
           }).always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               loader.hide();
           });
  }) 
}
```